# Pandas Pivot Table Nested Aggfunc

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I am trying to create a pivot table that counts the number of forms and the sum, mean and median from that count. However, the Forms dtype is categorical and I can't use the mean and median functions on a non-numeric value.

I want to use the 'Form Type':count as my value to aggregate.

I would get this error if I were to include the mean inside the first aggfunc

```
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Is there a way to nest aggfuncts in pivot tables or change the dtype while creating the pivot table?

I've tried using .astype(int) but I can't seem to figure out the syntax for that function.

The dummy code below isn't entirely accurate, but I can keep working on it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar"],
                   "B": ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two", "one", "one", "two", "two"],
                   "C": ["105319", "1271075", "84565", "84354", "54835", "81638", "1282224", "41856", "78987"],
                   "Form Type": ["144", "D", "D/A", "144", "D", "D", "D", "S-1","D"]})
```

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df, columns = ['Form Type'],
                       index=['A', 'B', 'C'],
                       fill_value =' ', 
                       aggfunc={'Form Type': ['count']})
```

The output looks similar to this

[image]

Comment: We can help you better if you can provide even the smallest dummy code. 5-10 records should work.

Comment: @JeromeMontino is an output what you needed or do you need the code beforehand?

Comment: You should define ```values``` i.e. columns, which you actually want to aggregate. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html

Comment: It might be help to include an example of what you want the output to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use `.value_counts()` to count `Form Type`:

- This assumes you're asking for the counts of `Form Type` and then you want the `mean`, `median` and `sum` of `counts`

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar"],
                   "B": ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two", "one", "one", "two", "two"],
                   "C": ["105319", "1271075", "84565", "84354", "54835", "81638", "1282224", "41856", "78987"],
                   "Form Type": ["144", "D", "D/A", "144", "D", "D", "D", "S-1","D"]})


counts = df['Form Type'].value_counts().rename_axis('Form Type').reset_index(name='counts')

Form Type  counts
        D       5
      144       2
      S-1       1
      D/A       1

counts['counts'].agg(['mean', 'median', 'sum'])

# Output:
mean      2.25
median    1.50
sum       9.00
Name: counts, dtype: float64
```

#### Alternative:

- If you want to get the `.value_counts` based upon `groupby`

```py
grouped_counts = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['Form Type'].value_counts().rename_axis(['A', 'B', 'Form Type']).reset_index(name='counts')

   A    B Form Type  counts
 bar  one         D       2
 bar  two         D       1
 bar  two       S-1       1
 foo  one       144       1
 foo  one         D       1
 foo  one       D/A       1
 foo  two       144       1
 foo  two         D       1

grouped_counts_stats = grouped_counts.groupby(['A', 'B', 'Form Type'])['counts'].agg(['mean', 'median', 'sum'])
```

[image]

Comment: I want to use the Form Type as the column I want to aggregate, but using the count of the Forms to get the mean, median, and sum. However, I can't apply the .astype function on the column because it doesn't show up after I call df.

I'm going to expand on my dummy code.

Comment: Oh, I did not, I refreshed and saw it. I'll give this a try. Thanks.

Comment: I'm getting a `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable` using the grouped_counts line. I'll follow your advice too and take a picture of the desired output.

Comment: I had to use `df.rename(columns{})` instead of `.rename_axis` for some reason. It worked after that.